# How do the laravel factory helper functions work with regards to namespacing?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

Okay, so this is a fairly specific question, I am not necessarily anticipating a response but would be great if someone could point me in the right direction for an answer. So I've been reading up on Laravel's documentation, and I encountered one part (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#basic-responses) that has the following advice regarding generating a response object:

> Returning a full Response instance allows you to customize the
>   response's HTTP status code and headers. A Response instance inherits
>   from the Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response class, providing a
>   variety of methods for building HTTP responses:
>
> ```
> use Illuminate\Http\Response;
>
> Route::get('home', function () {
>     return (new Response($content, $status))
>                   ->header('Content-Type', $value); 
> });
> ```
>
> For convenience, you may also use the response helper:
>
> ```
> Route::get('home', function () {
>     return response($content, $status)
>            ->header('Content-Type', $value); 
> });
> ```

So my question is, regarding the latter code example, how come they no longer need to include the `use Illuminate\Http\Response;` import? Or more specifically, what is going on within the response() function that means we don't have to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually standard [PHP namespacing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), rather than something unique Laravel is doing. The `use` statement is only required when using a namespaced class.

The `response()` helper function is not namespaced (it lives in the global namespace), so it doesn't need a `use` statement.

The `Illuminate\Http\Response` class is namespaced,  so it needs a `use` statement.

The Laravel helper functions reside in [vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/f424d3e86f87268a6cd0ac05e00f354b977cda15/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php), and this file does not have a namespace set. If it did, you would see `namespace Illuminate/Foundation` at the top of it.

Comment: No, what's happening is response() function is using fully qualified class name, so it doesn't need to import the class via `use` keyword. You'd get an error even if you weren't under any namespace and tried to call Response.

Comment: @IlyasSerter Um, no, that's completely wrong. The `response()` function lives in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`, which is a non-namespaced (e.g. global namespace) file. It's not a "fully qualified class name", as there's no class involved at all. It's a simple function. I stand by my answer.

Comment: `response()` function obviously don't belong to any class or namespace.  what I'm saying is, the function is using fully qualified class name  to refer to the Response factory and making an instance of Response class. I assumed @LeonAves already understands how response() is called, and he's asking what's going on in the inside.